# How to Auto run PHP file on windows server?

Tags: php, cmd

I am a newbie of PHP
and I would like to create a php file that can autorun on the windows server at a specific time.

any idea to achieve??

My PHP File

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
  // use exec() because no results are returned
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "New record created successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Anyidea, Thank you very much.

Comment: You've posted some code, but your question seems to have nothing to do with it. I'd guess you want help with the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may execute a php on windows machine thru the command line:

```
 “php c:\[directory]\[folder]\[phpscript].php”.
```

So if you want the machine to execute it every day at a specified time, please put the command into the windows scheduler and set the time.

Answer (score 0):

First create .bat file and show the file location as per below.

```
php D:\wamp\www\test\test.php
```

You can do by window scheduler from your window machine. Then your file will auto run at your specific mentioned time.